# Django: how to effectively use select_related() with Paginator?

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have 2 related models with 10 Million rows each and want to perform an efficient paginated request of 50 000 items of one of them and access related data on the other one:

```
class RnaPrecomputed(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=22, primary_key=True)
    rna = models.ForeignKey('Rna', db_column='upi', to_field='upi', related_name='precomputed')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Rna(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id')
    upi = models.CharField(max_length=13, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField()
    userstamp = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

As you can see, `RnaPrecomputed` is related to `RNA` via a foreign key. Now, I want to fetch a specific page of 50 000 items of `RnaPrecomputed` and corresponding `Rna`s related to them. I expect N+1 requests problem, if I do this without `select_related()` call. Here are the timings:

---

First, for reference I won't touch the related model at all:

```
rna_paginator = paginator.Paginator(RnaPrecomputed.objects.all(), 50000)
message = ""
for object in rna_paginator.page(400).object_list:
    message = message + str(object.id)
```

Takes:

```
real    0m12.614s
user    0m1.073s
sys 0m0.188s
```

---

Now, I'll try accessing data on related model:

```
rna_paginator = paginator.Paginator(RnaPrecomputed.objects.all(), 50000)
message = ""
for object in rna_paginator.page(400).object_list:
    message = message + str(object.rna.upi)
```

it takes:

```
real    2m27.655s
user    1m20.194s
sys 0m4.315s
```

Which is a lot, so, probably I have N+1 requests problem.

---

But now, if I use `select_related()`,

```
rna_paginator = paginator.Paginator(RnaPrecomputed.objects.all().select_related('rna'), 50000)
message = ""
for object in rna_paginator.page(400).object_list:
    message = message + str(object.rna.upi)
```

it takes even more:

```
real    7m9.720s
user    0m1.948s
sys 0m0.337s
```

So, somehow `select_related()` made things 3 times slower, instead of making them faster. And probably without it, I have N+1 requests, so for each entry of `RnaPrecomputed`, Django ORM probably has to do an additional request to the database to fetch the corresponding `Rna`?

What am I doing wrong and how to make `select_related()` perform well with paginated queryset?

Comment: It would be useful to see what the queries are and how long they are taking, rather than the overall time.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for interest. I'm willing to provide information that you request, but not sure, what you mean exactly. Are you speaking of SQL requests?

Comment: Yes, the SQL queries. You could use Django Debug toolbar or `connection.queries` to do this.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm AFK, I'll provide those data in an hour. Probably, they'll help me understand, what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth checking that you're not missing an index in your database. You have `db_index=True` for the `Rna.upi` field, but are you sure the index exists in the database?

If the `select_related` is making the `count()` query slow, then you could try doing the `select_related` on the paginated `object_list`.

```
for object in rna_paginator.page(300).object_list.select_related():
    message = message + str(object.rna.upi)
```